# How can I set a post thumbnail image without making a featured image?

Tags: post-thumbnails, archives, design

When I set a featured image, it is allways on the upper left corner of the post. Sometimes, like in this [example post](http://martin-thoma.com/compare-planet-sizes/), I only have very few text and one image. But this image should not be on the upper left corner of the post.

Is there any way how I can this little post thumbnail image in the [tag-overview](http://martin-thoma.com/tag/learning/) / category-overview without having it in my post? Could I tell wordpress that the image in the middle of the post is the featured image?

Answer (score 1):

This is your theme specific to show featured image in single post view.

I think you're using [Modern Style](http://flexithemes.com/themes/modern-style/) theme, just remove following code from `single.php` on line 14, now featured images only will be shown on tag/category archive pages (and I think on main page too ).

```
<?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(array(300,225), array("class" => "alignleft post_thumbnail")); } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped a lot. Do you know if there is a way to make it optional? That means I would like to check / uncheck that I use the featured image at the upper left corner.

Comment: This line is also in page.php and index.php. In index.php it is "(array(200,160)", but I guess I have to delete it there, too.

Comment: @moose in index.php shows featured images on your site's homepage, it's already optional, I mean you can set/unset featured image, maybe there is a plugin that adds more option where to show featured images search in WordPress plugin directory